# Time-out while applying Istio virtual services

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-cloud, istio

Applying the virtual-service.yaml yields to a timeout (30s) with kubectl   apply -f.

On Monday did I reconfigure my virtual services at ISTIO-1.2.4 as usual. Today I run into timeouts applying the virtual-service. 
What I did

```
% kubectl -n istio-system apply -f virtual-service.yaml
Error from server (Timeout): error when creating "virtual-service.yaml": Timeout: request did not complete within requested timeout 30s
% kubectl -n istio-system delete pod istio-ingressgateay*
% kubectl -n istio-system exec istio-ingressgateway*  -c istio-proxy -- curl -X POST http://localhost:15000/logging?level=debug
% kubectl -n istio-system logs --follow istio-ingressgateway* -c istio-proxy
% kubectl -n istio-system get gateways.networking.istio.io
NAME                         AGE
istio-gateway   3d19h
% kubectl -n istio-system get virtualservices.networking.istio.io
NAME                               GATEWAYS                       HOSTS                      AGE
infrastructure-istio-k8s-ingress   [istio-gateway]   [${DOMAIN}]   3d19h
%
```

And I still get 30s timeout message and no new virtual services and I do not anything in the log related to the virtual service.

The configuration virtual-service.yaml looks like

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: default-istio-k8s-ingress
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  gateways:
  - istio-gateway-149-81-86-74
  hosts:
  - "test.procom.energy"
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        regex: "/head.*s"
    rewrite:
      uri: "/headers"
    route:
    - destination:
        host: httpbin.default.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 8000
      weight: 100
  - match:
    - uri:
        exact: /ip
    route:
    - destination:
        host: httpbin.default.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 8000
      weight: 100
  - match:
    - uri:
        exact: /user-agent
    route:
    - destination:
        host: httpbin.default.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 8000
      weight: 100
```

I would expect a new applied virtual service and I only see timeouts. 
In this case do I not have any possibilities to reconfigure virtual services or apply new ones.

Answer (score 1):

Hej you.

I fixed it. After disappointing deep look and see nothing did I reload all POD 
(over a for loop). After that I rebootet all our nodes and deleted all replicasets
in the istio-system namespace I may reconfigure or apply my virtual services.

Best regards,
Jan